# Karaf error installing OSGi bundle listed in startup.properties with url

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf, karaf-maven-plugin

I am getting following error while Karaf comes up:

Error installing bundle listed in `startup.properties` with url - mvn:org.apache.karaf.service/org.apache.karaf.service.guard/3.0.6 = 10

Content of `startup.properties` is as follows:

```
mvn\:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-aether/2.4.5 = 5
mvn\:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-wrap/2.4.5/jar/uber = 5
mvn\:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-api/1.8.4 = 8
#mvn\:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-service/1.8.4 = 8
mvn\:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-logback/1.8.4 = 8
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.service/org.apache.karaf.service.guard/3.0.6 = 10
mvn\:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.configadmin/1.8.4 = 10
mvn\:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.fileinstall/3.5.2 = 11
mvn\:org.ow2.asm/asm-all/5.0.3 = 12
mvn\:org.apache.aries/org.apache.aries.util/1.1.1 = 20
mvn\:org.apache.aries.proxy/org.apache.aries.proxy.api/1.0.1 = 20
mvn\:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.cm/1.0.7 = 20
mvn\:org.apache.aries.proxy/org.apache.aries.proxy.impl/1.0.4 = 20
mvn\:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.api/1.0.1 = 20
mvn\:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.core.compatibility/1.0.0 = 20
mvn\:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.core/1.4.4 = 20
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.deployer/org.apache.karaf.deployer.spring/3.0.6 = 24
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.deployer/org.apache.karaf.deployer.blueprint/3.0.6 = 24
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.deployer/org.apache.karaf.deployer.wrap/3.0.6 = 24
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.region/org.apache.karaf.region.core/3.0.6 = 25
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.features/org.apache.karaf.features.core/3.0.6 = 25
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.deployer/org.apache.karaf.deployer.features/3.0.6 = 26
mvn\:jline/jline/2.13 = 30
mvn\:org.jledit/core/0.2.1 = 30
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.features/org.apache.karaf.features.command/3.0.6 = 30
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.bundle/org.apache.karaf.bundle.core/3.0.6 = 30
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.bundle/org.apache.karaf.bundle.command/3.0.6 = 30
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.shell/org.apache.karaf.shell.console/3.0.6 = 30
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.jaas/org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules/3.0.6 = 30
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.jaas/org.apache.karaf.jaas.config/3.0.6 = 30
mvn\:org.apache.sshd/sshd-core/0.14.0 = 30
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.shell/org.apache.karaf.shell.help/3.0.6 = 30
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.shell/org.apache.karaf.shell.table/3.0.6 = 30
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.system/org.apache.karaf.system.core/3.0.6 = 30
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.system/org.apache.karaf.system.command/3.0.6 = 30
mvn\:org.apache.karaf.shell/org.apache.karaf.shell.commands/3.0.6 = 30
mvn\:org.apache.aries.quiesce/org.apache.aries.quiesce.api/1.0.0 = 30
```

Any idea what could be reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the URIs (with scheme `mvn:`) specified in `etc/startup.properties` are translated directly by Karaf when it starts.

It's not possible to actually *resolve* `mvn:` URI, because `mvn\:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-aether/2.4.5` bundle is the one that can perform such resolution and we'd have chicken&egg problem here.

So Karaf translates these `mvn:` URIs to `file:` URIs pointing to `${karaf.home}/system`. For example `mvn\:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-logback/1.8.4` → `file:${karaf.home}/system/org/ops4j/pax/logging/pax-logging-logback/1.8.4/pax-logging-logback-1.8.4.jar`.

If it's not found, it's not resolved. Please ensure you have the bundle `org.apache.karaf.service.guard-3.0.6.jar` in `system/` directory of Karaf.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will check it.